# Wordpress is giving me the latest post Id instead of the blog page id

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to set content in some div which is specifical for the page where the posts are shown.
This page is Blog and has an ID of 44. In the settings/reading/post page is set up as the page to show posts.

Now in the header of my template I set up the_ID() to get the id of the page, so I can see it.

When I go to the Blog page, instead of getting the ID 44 as supposed I am getting 398 and everytime I create a new post this number increases, so the blog page is using the latest post id instead of the blog page id.

How can I get the blog page id when I am in that page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is, In the blog you are listing the latest posts.
So whenever you are adding new posts, it will be showing up and the ID of the latest post will be showing.

So you please try to get the "the_ID()" above the loop,(that is the have_posts() loop).

You will be getting the page id above the loop.

Orelse get the page id by the page slug name.

Hope this works for you.